# What is more appropriate translation of "running store"?

Tags: translation

What is more appropriate translation of "running store" (as a writing on the store for chinese customers unfamiliar with the place, so it is not online store)?

> 跑步商店 OR 跑步机专卖店

Also it would be nice to see some explanation.

As for me the second one seems to be right version but it does not look laconic as the first one.

Comment: what's a running store?

Comment: @user3306356, Running store is a store where anyone can buy clothing, running equipment, running shoes also can get some consultation about the stuff one is going to buy

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Running store translated to "跑步用品商店" or "跑步用品店" is correct.

But "**跑步用品专门店**" sounds more professional and more attractive to consumers.  (everything related to the running sport is there)

- 专门店 means a store is specialized in one subject. For example: 手机专门店, 皮革专门店, 婚礼服专门店
- 专卖店 should means a store is authorized to sell specific goods that needed to be authorized. For example: 香烟专卖店, 洋酒专卖店. But many people just use it interchangeably with 专门店.

Comment: Thank! Very useful

Answer (score 2):

Does the store sell equipment for running or only sells running machines? If it is the first one, the translate should be more appropriate to be "跑步用品商店"；if it is the second one, then it is correct to say "跑步机专卖店".

Comment: In my case it seems that "跑步用品商店" is the right one. What about "跑步用品专门店" version?

Comment: I guess that there is only style difference. "专门店" sounds (for me) like store for professional runners, who is more experienced in running etc.

Comment: @IvanGerasimenko Actually, 专卖店means the store only sells particular kind of things. Such as 手机专卖店 only sells cellphones